# Alias/Synonym for a database based on user

Tags: sql, sql-server, mssql-jdbc

Is it possible to have the same query, but based on different user currently logged in, request the info from different databases?

An example: we have an application with different environments dev/test/int etc. For each environment, we have different JDBC connections to the MSSQL Server. The main idea is, to have always the same query like:

```
SELECT * FROM config_db.clients
```

But internally, based on current user in the connection string (like user_dev, user_test and so on) get the response from config_db_dev, config_db_test etc.? I hope the question makes sense.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: *"Is it possible to have the same query, but based on different user currently logged in, request the info from different databases?"* No. SQL works on literals, not inferred information. If you want different users to connect to different databases, you need to configure that in your application, with connection strings.

Comment: Not sure this helps, but I've seen cases where instead of separate databases different users connect based on schema within the same database. Data retrieval is then all based on DB Views which are restricted to the relevant user's/schema's data, and the users have default schemas making it unnecessary to specify the schema when retrieving data.

Comment: A suggestion is to create stored procedures which would take the userId as a parameter and run a dynamic SQL query pointing to the environment they need access to. Not the most elegant solution perhaps, but could suffice for testing purposes.

Comment: Store the config table within the same database as the "environment"? Maybe a  synonym defined in the user's default schema? But I fear you are over-complicating things and perhaps increasing the chances that someone works in the wrong database accidentally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to have the same query, but based on different user currently logged in, request the info from different databases?

Sure.  Logins have a [default database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-login-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) and users have a [default schema](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-user-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

Both of these can affect object name resolution.

if you use a 1-part name, like

```
SELECT * FROM clients
```

then SQL Server will look for an object named "clients" in the user's default schema first, then in the dbo schema in the current database.

If you use a 2-part name, like

```
SELECT * FROM foo.clients
```

then SQL Server will look for an object named "clients" in in the "foo" schema in the current database.

Comment: Hi David, that's sounds quite simple! I will test it tonight. Many thanks!